# Using Auth with Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I defined a simple API using Google Cloud Endpoints:

```
@Api(name = "realestate", version = "v1", clientIds = { com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }, scopes = {
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" })
public class RealEstatePropertyV1 {

    @ApiMethod(name = "create", path = "properties", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public void create(RealEstateProperty property, User user)
            throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Must log in");
        }
        System.out.println(user.getEmail());
    }

}
```

Then I try to test it using the `API explorer`. I activated OAuth 2.0. But when I execute the request, the `User` object is `null`.

```
Jun 23, 2013 10:21:50 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Jun 23, 2013 10:22:42 AM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet init
INFO: SPI restricted: true
Jun 23, 2013 10:22:43 AM com.google.api.server.spi.WebApisUserService getCurrentUser
WARNING: getCurrentUser: clientId  not allowed
Jun 23, 2013 10:22:43 AM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
INFO: cause={0}
com.google.api.server.spi.response.UnauthorizedException: Must log in
    at com.realestate.api.v1.RealEstatePropertyV1.create(RealEstatePropertyV1.java:44)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `getCurrentUser: clientId  not allowed` indicates that the client ID associated with the token is the empty string. This doesn't seem possible and may be a strange bug/quirk.

You should check the token sent in the request, it will be in the `Request` section in something like

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29....
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

and your token is the one that starts with `ya29.`. You should make sure the token info checks out by sending it into the tokeninfo API:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo
```

Comment: I got my token and then passed it to the `oauth2.tokeninfo`. The response is `200` with my correct email. The `issued_to` part correspond to the clientId `com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID`.

Comment: Interesting, this seems like it could be a bug. Is this behavior happening in production or dev appserver? Is it consistent or intermittent?

Comment: It's only on dev appserver since I did not deploy my app on app engine. It's consistent, I can reproduce all the time. Should I create a ticket in app engine issue tracker? Or do you have any idea on what I can check to see if it's really a bug. I don't know if it's related but I created a simple test using `LocalServiceTestHelper` and it always return `null` when calling `userService.getCurrentUser()`. The code is `LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalUserServiceTestConfig()).setEnvIsAdmin(true).setEnvIsLoggedIn(true);`

Comment: It seems this is a defect with the dev appserver, you can [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3) using a [template](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Type%3DDefect).

Comment: I switched back to 1.8.0, and now it works. I created an issue [#9598](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9598) because it's not working with 1.8.1.1

Comment: I had similar problem - switching from 1.8.2 to 1.8.0 solves this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still an issue?  I am getting this on 1.9.17